# Nilpotent symmetry group in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, lie-algebra

>

Hello everyone,

I have two questions concerning symmetries in classical mechanics.

1) I am looking for examples of a lagrangian or hamiltonian model with a symmetry group which is a nilpotent or solvable non-abelian Lie group (and not part of a bigger semi-simple group). If possible not with too many degrees of freedom.

2) Even if I'm curious about general examples as in question 1), I would like more precisely such a (hamiltonian) model where the Poisson bracket of the moment map with itself admits a non-trivial central extension, *i.e.* a bracket with a non-coboundary cocycle.

The examples I know where there is an extension are translation symmetry in constant magnetic field or the galilean invariance for a free non-relativstic particle. I was wondering if there was example with more "internal/hidden" symmetries.

I'm interested in any complete answer / partial answer / comment / hint / reference on the subject. Thank you in advance.